# Linux kernel Scheduler variable "vruntime"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

What is vruntime variable defined in the linux scheduler structure. Is this the total time the process spend in memory from its loaded initially to now, Or is it the total time it used the processor or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

What is Virtual run time?

Virtual run time is the weighted time a task has run on the CPU

Where is it stored?
Virtual run time is stored in vruntime member of struct sched_entity
Note that sched_entity contains scheduling related information of task and it is member of task_struct.

For more info read the below link

http://oakbytes.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/linux-scheduler-cfs-and-virtual-run-time/